# XBAP application manifest download issue in multiple publish scenario

Tags: manifest, publish, xbap

we have an XBAP application. The XBAP is hosted in IIS in a website.

The same application is deployed in multiple environments, but the assembly versions numbers are kept different in different environments.

Only certain users complaining about not being able to access only certain environments. What I have observed is that once they access an environment that is browsable, the manifests get downloaded in AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/... folder. After that when they try to access another environment they get an error. See the error details below -

**ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.  * An exception occurred while downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected:        + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly .dll.**

Strange thing is that even after deleting all the content from AppData/Local/Apps/2.0 folder and then trying to access the URL (that is not working) gives the same error message.

How do we deploy the XBAP - for the XBAP project we have a post build event that copies all the output to a specific folder in a web project and we host the XBAP in an html already present in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because, project->properties->publish-> automatically increment revision with each publish, is checked. so each time you run the app, the version increments in the manifest.

For deploying XBAP, please have a look into the following link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: We do not auto increment revision with each deployment. We do it through a custom logic implemented through MS build. Nonetheless, can you please explain why having a different version would create problem?